# Dynamic input in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create an `ArrayList` in which you can add input that is non-fixed, so you can add input later.
Currently I have two issues:

- the elements of the `ArrayList` aren't being printed.
- I can only input one element, instead of an infinite amount.

Thanks

Code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> shopList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter an item: ");
        String item = sc.nextLine();
        shopList.add(item);
    }
    System.out.println("The Grocery List: " +shopList);
    sc.close();
}
```

Comment: The loop is running forever, so the println list never get executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should [code to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992384/program-to-an-interface-what-does-it-mean). `ArrayList` is the implementation. [List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) is the interface.

You have an [infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173481/when-would-you-write-an-infinite-loop-in-java). You need to decide on how to terminate the loop, otherwise code after the loop will not get executed.

In fact, when I copied your code to my [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) IDE, it flagged the following line of the code as *Unreachable code*

```java
System.out.println("The Grocery List: " +shopList);
```

In the below code, I decided that simply hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> will terminate the loop.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShopList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> shopList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter an item (or just hit 'ENTER' to quit): ");
            String item = sc.nextLine();
            if (item.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                shopList.add(item);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The Grocery List: " +shopList);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Output from a sample run:
(Note that the second last entry was the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key and in the last entry, I hit the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> by itself which meant that `item` was an empty string.)

```
Enter an item (or just hit 'ENTER' to quit): s
Enter an item (or just hit 'ENTER' to quit): %
Enter an item (or just hit 'ENTER' to quit): mvosp[5rt04j89w
Enter an item (or just hit 'ENTER' to quit): *&^$^&$ghdtr d df
Enter an item (or just hit 'ENTER' to quit):    
Enter an item (or just hit 'ENTER' to quit): 
The Grocery List: [s, %, mvosp[5rt04j89w, *&^$^&$ghdtr d df,    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a great use case for a `do...while()` loop:

```
String item;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

List<String> shopList = new ArrayList<String>();
do {
    System.out.print("Enter an item [Enter to quit]: ");
    item = sc.nextLine();
    if (!item.isEmpty()) {
      shopList.add(item);
    }
} while (!item.isEmpty());

System.out.println("The Grocery List: " + shopList);
sc.close();
```

Sample run:

```
Enter an item [Enter to quit]: pizza crust
Enter an item [Enter to quit]: pizza sauce
Enter an item [Enter to quit]: pepperoni
Enter an item [Enter to quit]: cheese
Enter an item [Enter to quit]: 
The Grocery List: [pizza crust, pizza sauce, pepperoni, cheese]
```